# How to terminate while loop using fscanf with stdin stream

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

I am in a bit trouble, I am asking input from keyboard using fscanf()  library function using stdin stream.

```
#define STOP '.'

char str[100];           //string variable
while( (fscanf(stdin,"%s",str) ) == 1)  {
           //code
           //code
}
```

// I want to terminate this loop if user hit enter, the things I already tried are :

```
1)while( (fscanf(stdin,"%s",str) ) > 0 )
2)while( (fscanf(stdin,"%s",str) ) < 0 )
3)while( (fscanf(stdin,"%s",str) ) == 1 && str[0] != '\n' )
```

// 3rd one with all combination of operators

```
4)while( (fscanf(stdin,"%s",str) ) == 1 && str[0] != '\0' )
```

//4th again with all operator combination

```
5)while( (fscanf(stdin,"%s",str) ) == 1 && str[0] != STOP )
```

//5 also with all the possible operators

I can use other functions , I know that , but I need this , because first for learning , as I searched and I haven't found anything and second, I m using this in function which is taking stream as parameter and I am changing stream in that function according to my need , for that I have to have use this function.

yeah, If somebody wants to say elaborate, I want my while loop to work exactly like this while ,

```
while( ( fgets(str,100,stdin) ) != NULL  && str[0] != '\n');
```

Comment: What is `input` and how is it filled?

Comment: Why can't you use this `while` loop with `fgets`?

Comment: Input is just name of book. @LPs

Comment: Because I am using this line with two streams, like if file is open , take file pointer , otherwise ask for input, and the reason I dont want to use fgets i I have structure which is full of pointer to string , so fscanf is working perfectly fine with those file entries. thanks @GMichael

Comment: Do you have spaces in the input?

Comment: @DeveshPratap I do not see any difference between `fscanf()` and `fgets()/sscanf()` combination. Try it

Comment: yeah, but Its acting weird while I m trying to read from file, its reading whole line and by using fscanf I am taking one word as my input. and while input its same, but I dont want to increase my code with 2 more extra lines.., is there any way to terminate ?? @GMichael

Comment: @DeveshPratap I do not know any way to do what you want without `fgets`

Comment: there is no input, I have just edited that, @Aif

Comment: Try: `while((fscanf(stdin,"%100[^\n]%c",str,&ch))==2 && ch=='\n') {...`

Comment: if you use linux terminal you can change terminal input settings then '\n' character is not ignored and you can compare it for exiting loop.

Comment: its working , thank u, could you explain me, why you use this ch and [^\n] @Bob__

Comment: It should work also `while((fscanf(stdin,"%100[^\n]%*c",str)==1) {...` [^\n] force to read till a newline (it means all but), %*c consume the newline (read a char without storing it). If there is only a newline fscanf will return 0.

Comment: ... And it should be 99 not 100...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `fscanf(stdin,"%s",str)`, you cannot terminate the loop when the user hits Enter.  It is because the `%s` format reads the next word from the input stream.  When the user hits Enter, it continues to read from the input stream until it finds a word.

You may use `fgets` as others suggested.  You may read the input character by character and parse it.  You may require the user to press Ctrl-D (in Unix) rather than Enter, because Ctrl-D reports EOF.  You may even use `curses`.  With `fscanf(stdin,"%s",str)` and Enter, the problem is unsolvable.